# first element of div style is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Can you help me to know why this first-of-type css is not working?

```css
.item:first-of-type .delete{
    display: none ;
}

.delete { text-decoration: none; color: red; padding-top: 40px;}

.add_form_field { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<div id="dimensions" class="row item">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Longueur(cm):</label>
      <input type="number"  min="0" name="longueurs[]" id="length"  value="<?php //echo $length;?>" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Largeur(cm):</label>
      <input type="number"  min="0" name="largeurs[]" id="width" value="<?php //echo $width;?>" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Hauteur(cm):</label>
      <input type="number"  min="0" name="hauteurs[]" id="height" value="<?php //echo $height;?>" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label>Poids(Kg):</label>
      <input type="text"  min="0" name="poids[]" id="weight" value="<?php //echo $weight;?>"required>
   </div>
   <!--div class="col-sm-1"-->
   <br><br>
   <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
   <!--/div-->
</div>
<!-- row dimensions item -->
<div class="col-md-3" style="">
   <!-- button add -->
   <br>
   <button class="add_form_field">Ajouter un colis</button>
</div>
```

How can I do to resolve that? There is an  other way to hide first delate element ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What specifically isn't working as expected?  Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: Your .delete class is not displayed just like you specified. What's the issue here?

Comment: the first element of the classe delate not hidden

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
.delete:first-of-type{
display: none;
}
```

or:

```
.delete:first-of-type{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanx but it is not wokng

Comment: Sorry, but for me is working.